Problem 1 Glove off - error while counting numerator
Question:
You have $5$ pairs of gloves that each have a distinct number $1−5$. The $10$ gloves are randomly paired up. Find the probability that the gloves are paired up such that the values of any pair differ by at most $1$.
My Approach
I tried to find number of such arrangements by writing down all types:

$(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)$
$(1,2), (2,1), (3,3)$
$(1,1), (2,3), (3,2)$
$(3,3), (4,5), (5,4)$
$(4,3), (3,4), (5,5)$

Total should be ((1.)+(2.))((1.)+(4.)) - (1.) + (3.) * 2 + (5.) *2 (ie. $2\times 2 - 1 + 2 + 2 = 5$
Each arragement can be arranged $5!$ ways. Hence total $5\times 5!$
Denominator is $10!/(2!)^5$. So, probability turns out $\frac{1}{9\times 7\times 3}$.
The Answer is not right. What I am doing wrong here?
P.S.
I apologize for any type of confusion created by me, and I totally ignored the property of left and right glove pairing (silly me). Practically speaking, it is just a very easy problem, and posting it here makes me feel ashamed. In any case, I have accepted the solution given by @CiaPan, for it just being elegant! Again, I really apologize.
Also note that the question originated from this link and the answer accepted in this thread (which is 1/15) is not quite right. But to me, the solutions posted here look perfectly fine; hence, hell with whatever the answer website is expecting.

Why do your lists in $2$ through $5$ include only three pairs?  Each includes two different acceptable arrangements?  I also don't see how you conclude that each arrangement can be arranged $5!$ ways.  Finally, let's make an assumption explicit.  Can we assume that left gloves are distinguishable from right gloves and that each pair consists of a left glove and a right glove?

@RobertShore "Can we assume that left gloves are distinguishable from right gloves and that each pair consists of a left glove and a right glove?", Are you talking about this for each pair? If a pair contains the same number-marked balls, then those are indistinguishable, otherwise distinguishable.

Gloves are normally supposed to have distinct left and right, like shoes, whereas socks are taken to be indistinguishable between left and right. If it is a "shoe" like  problem, I can offer a method, whereas if it is a "socks" like problem, it is highly complex. Please confirm if  the "book/teacher" has specifically said that left and right of a pair are indistonguishable. I have a feeling that  you are putting this condition.

In brief, if you clarify that left and right are distinguishable (as gloves are) then only can i give you an  answer

hi @trueblueanil, To be fair, I have a lot less knowledge about glove balls than you (probably a lot less than anyone who knows about gloves, and maybe equal knowledge to those who know only that the word/game glove exists). Hence, I really like to know if it is a shoe problem or a socks problem. I will try myself in that case and edit my approach. (I came across this problem here: https://www.quantguide.io/questions/1-glove-off)

@abomasnow, I thought there was one color, all (say) red, and marked k for each pair, $k=1,..,5$. I am really confused now, i.e.., my thought was to arrange $1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5$ so that it follows the condition mentioned.

@abomasnow If I use your rephrase of the problem, then this is how I am thinking: $(1,1),(2,2)$ can be arranged 3 ways, choosing two boxes from 5, is $5C2$, remaining $(3,3),(4,4)$ can be arranged in 3 ways; choosing 2 boxes from remaining 3 is $3C2$, so, total favourable cases, $30\times 3^3$. all cases is $10!$. Does it look okay?

Let $F(n)$ denote a number of possible pairing of $n$ pairs of gloves.
Let's order all the left-hand gloves by their numbers and consider assigning right-hand gloves to them.
The first right-hand glove's number must not differ by more than one from $1$ (the first left-hand glove's number), so it can be either $1$ or $2$.

If it's $1$, then there are $F(n-1)$ possible arrangements of the remaining gloves (those with numbers $2\dots n$),
and if it's $2$, then the second must be $1$ and there are $F(n-2)$ possible arrangements of gloves numbered $3 \dots n$.

As a result, $$F(n)=F(n-2)+F(n-1)$$ with the basic cases of

$F(0)=1$ as there is one way to pair gloves if we don't have any (an empty set of pairs $\{\}$), and
$F(1)=1$ because there's just one way to pair a single pair of gloves $\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}$.

Hopefully, you can recognize this formula, and even if you don't you can easily calculate N(5) $F(5)$ with it.

I guess you meant $F(5)$, which is $8$. If we also consider reverse order, then total should be $16$. Total number of cases is $10!$. Hence the answer should be $16/10!$.

That is what I also wrote down in the answer of "true ball anil"'s first comment but calculated manually, but I have put down this answer to verify in the website, it's not really the answer.

Btw it's a very clever solution, I was just looking for these solutions like this.

Yes, I meant $F$. I used N in the first version of my answer, then changed it to F. When adding the last sentence later, I mistakenly used the original symbol. Fixed.

@MAN-MADE What do you mean by 'reverse order'? As far as I can understand the problem you describe, you are counting pairing of gloves, not their ordering. Reversing order, for example presenting the perfect match $${\langle 1,1\rangle, \langle 2,2\rangle, \langle 3, 3\rangle, \langle 4,4\rangle, \langle 5,5\rangle}$$ as $${\langle 5,5\rangle, \langle 4,4\rangle, \langle 3, 3\rangle, \langle 2,2\rangle, \langle 1,1\rangle}$$ adds nothing to the solution – it's still the same set of pairs, i.e. the same single pairing.

@MAN-MADE Where did you get the denominator $10!$ from in this comment...?

The total number of arrangements of 10 items is $10!$, right? All items are distinct, so...

I totally lost track of properties gloves hold and just complicating things. The total number of arrangements is 5!

I am accepting this solution as it is just elegant!

Do we get to assume that each pair of the mismatched gloves includes one left glove and one right glove?
If this is the case there are 5! ways to match gloves.
Now how many have the numbers one off?
Let's introduce cycle notation.  e.g. $(1,2,3)(4,5)$ would represent that the one left glove matches with the #2 right glove.  The #2 left glove matches with the #3 right glove.  The #3 left glove matches with the #1 right glove.  The left 4 is matched with the right 5 and the right 4 is matched with the left 5.
If all gloves are matched to within 1 of their mate, there are no cycles longer than 2, and all cycles are of adjacent digits.
(123)(45) would not be a permutation that puts all gloves within 1 of their mate.
$(23)$ is the single tranposition of the gloves numbered 2 and 3.
$(23)(45)$ is a double tranposition.
The set we are trying to count includes 4 single transpositions, 3 double transpositions, and the case that all gloves are correctly matched.
8 combinations.
$\frac {8}{120}$
If left gloves can be matched with other left gloves it is not that much harder to count the possibilities.
We still have the same rules of what cycles keep all gloves getting paired to within 1 of their number, but we must also count how whether in a transposition is the paring homo-chiral or hetero-chiral.  (i.e. two LR pairs or a LL and RR)
1 identity, 8 single transpositions, 12 double transpositions.

After seeing your solution, now I see how easy this problem is and how much I was complicating things. I totally lost track of the properties gloves hold.

Simplified Answer
The question is not about "glove balls" but about gloves. Clearly, gloves for the left hand and right hand are necessariy distinct.
Further, mismatches are to be considered only within each pair (ie left and right differ by only one number if mismatched)

It is better to make a diagram with left on top and right at the bottom for clarity, and the left numbers can be put serially WLOG, eg for only one pair matched,

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
L & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
R & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 5 \\ \hline \end{array}$
There can be only $3$ valid cases here with $(11),\;or\;(3,3),\;or\; (5,5)$ matching

You will find that you can't have valid cases with exactly two pairs or exactly four pairs matching

For valid cases with three pairs matching, the two mismatched cases must be adjacent, thus $4$ such

And, of course, there is only one perfect match, so the total number of valid cases is $
3+4+1=8$

Finally, $Pr = \frac{8}{5!} = \frac1{15}$



if I understand it correctly, for B cases are: ((12)(12)(33)(44)(55)), ((11)(23)(23)(44)(55)),((11)(22)(34)(34)(55)), ((11)(22)(33)(45)(45)) | ((12)(12)(34)(34)(55)), ((12)(12)(33)(45)(45)),((11)(23)(23)(45)(45)) and reverse of all these cases.

3 pair mismatch is not possible, right?

You should count systematically as in PPS and finally compute probability

@abomasnow:  Okay, I just thought OP would relate more easily to gloves as in the question.

I am thinking about "one pair match": if I put $(22)$ fixed, I have no other option but to fix $(11)$ too, and that leads to a "three pair match" (as any of $(33),(55)$ have to be fixed too). Do you think my thought process is in the right direction?

Yes, you can't have one match with (2,2) or (4,4) so you need to count cautiously

Hi!, I was just complicating thins when it was just gloves and did not consider the properties of left and right gloves. Now I am just thinking how easy this problem is and how many complications I have created, my bad. btw, I have accepted the solution of @CiaPan for just giving such an elegant solution. (I have upvoted yours.)

All is good if you have got the correct answer !
